# Android : Using GPS

Tags: android

Is there any way by which i can get the last GPS location my application itself ????

Is there any API available which can show me the Lat and Long. of the place from where i have connected GPS last time.

Any help, much appriciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)Context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

Comment: import android.content.Context;
import android.location.LocationManager;

LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

Answer (score 1):

You can use the LocationManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html